# How to get the tree of the current directory in Git

Tags: git, git-ls-tree

In Git it's possible to get the tree of a sub-directory, say `foo/` like this

```bash
git ls-tree -d HEAD foo
```

but suppose `foo` is the current directory, how does one get the tree of that directory?

The following

```bash
git ls-tree -d HEAD .
```

would list any *trees* in `foo`, but not the *tree* of `foo`.

The best approach I have found is

```bash
git ls-tree -d HEAD $PWD
```

but I wonder if there is way to do this without relying on the `$PWD` environment variable.

Comment: Either `$PWD` environment variable or `$(pwd)`; the latter command is available in all shells though syntax could be different.

Comment: In a pinch, `git ls-tree -d HEAD .. | grep './$'`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 yeah, I thought about that one too but then I think I prefer using `$PWD`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, that would be:

```bash
git ls-tree -d HEAD $(pwd)
```

The `$(pwd)` [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) will execute the `pwd` command, which prints the working directory, and substitute its output into the command. That way, you are not directly relying on the `$PWD` environment variable. However, this still involves obtaining the path of the current directory.

Another alternative is to use a combination of `git rev-parse` and `git ls-tree` commands. Here is how you could do it:

```bash
git ls-tree -d HEAD:$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)
```

The [`git rev-parse --show-prefix` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-prefix) returns the prefix (i.e., the path from the repository root to the current directory), which can then be used with the `git ls-tree` command to obtain the tree of the current directory.

Comment: The combination of `ls-tree` and `rev-parse` is interesting, but I can't seem to get it to work :(

Comment: @CervEd What is your environment (Git version, shell, OS)?

Comment: I tried it in Git 2.42.0 using GNU bash, version 5.1.16 on Linux kernel 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Comment: `git ls-tree -d HEAD ../$(git rev-parse --show-prefix | sed 's@/$@@')` works, but any system that can do that can probably also do `$(pwd)`, read not `cmd.exe`. This also wouldn't work in the Git root.

Comment: @CervEd I confirm `cmd.exe` can do it (i.e. `git ls-tree -d HEAD $(pwd)`), using a git bash session. And it works in a Git repository root folder.

Comment: `git ls-tree -d HEAD $(pwd)` is probably preferred then. The combination of `rev-parse` and `ls-tree` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `-t` the first line will be the tree of the current directory:

```
git ls-tree -dt HEAD | head -1
```

According to the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree#Documentation/git-ls-tree.txt--t), `-d` implies `-t`, but that does not seem to be the case.

> ###### `-t`
>
> Show tree entries even when going to recurse them. Has no effect if
> `-r` was not passed.  `-d` implies `-t`.